# Symfony: accessing to another symfony REST API project

Tags: php, rest, api, symfony

This is my context:

I have two symfony REST API projects, and I want to do a relation between both projects. Each project uses his own database, entities and controllers.

From project 1 (client-api), I need to get access to entities of project 2 (product-api).
I have tried to use [DoctrineRestDriver](https://github.com/CircleOfNice/DoctrineRestDriver)

Firstly, I have configured the **config.yml** file of client-api project:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   "%database_driver%"
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            memory: "%database_memory%"
            path: "%database_path%"
            charset:  UTF8
        product_api:
            driver_class: "Circle\\DoctrineRestDriver\\Driver"
            host: "http://localhost"
            port: 8000
            user:
            password:
            options:
                authentication_class:  "HttpAuthentication"


orm:
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AppBundle:
        product_api:
            connection: product_api
            mappings:
                AppBundle:
```

I want to read a country (id = 1) from the product-api project, so I have created this controller function on client-api project:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/countries", name="countries_other_api")
 */
public function getTheCountriesFromOtherApi()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('product_api');
    $country = $em->find("AppBundle\Entity\Country", 1);
}
```

But I'm getting the eror:

> Class 'AppBundle\Entity\Pais' does not exist

Where is my problem ? How can I get access from symfony project 1 to symfony project 2 ?

Thanks.

Comment: First check `$em` value if it is works like what you want then try `$em->getRepository("AppBundle:Country")->find(1);`

Comment: I have checked it and I'm getting the same error..

Comment: Have you managed to create the scheme doctrine:scheme:create ? If it can't find the entity should throw some errors when creating/updating schema. You should also check class names, file names and namespaces. And also clearing cache or even deleting cache dir. In pass I hace suffered similar issues and the only way to solve was rm -rf app/cache/*

Answer (score 0):

So, you have 2 services. Each of service is responsible for its own entities. And you want service1 to have access directly to DB of service2...

My opinion is that you try to solve things in wrong way. If you want to get entities from service2 you should use REST API of service2 because you need to reimplement service2 logic in service1.

How to do it in better way? Create RestApi Client library for service2 and add it to service1 composer.json file. Dont forget to use authentication (hardcoded API keys or JWT...).

So, answer to your question 'where is problem?' I can say problem is in solution that you want to implement.